# Magento 2 Remove test data that is generated from Performance Toolkit?

Tags: magento2, performance, testing

I tried to test Magento 2 performance on my local computer by using the Magento Performance Toolkit,

```
php bin/magento setup:perf:generate-fixtures /var/www/html/magento2/setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/extra_large.xml
```

I wasn't aware that this command added almost a million products into the database, which made my testing site extremly slow. I would like to remove all the testing data that is generated from this Performance Tookit, but I couldn't find out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to delete only the profile data and keep your real data then run the below SQl on your database manager.

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE `sku` LIKE 'product_dynamic_%';
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE `sku` LIKE 'simple_product_%';
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE `sku` LIKE 'Configurable Product%'; 'configurable_product_%';
```

Finally reindex

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to delete only the profile data and keep your real data then run the below SQl on your database manager.

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE `sku` LIKE 'product_dynamic_%';
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE `sku` LIKE 'simple_product_%';
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE `sku` LIKE 'Configurable Product%'; 'configurable_product_%';
/***************************************************/
DELETE FROM eav_attribute_option WHERE attribute_id IN ( SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code LIKE "attribute%");
DELETE FROM eav_attribute_option_value WHERE option_id NOT IN ( SELECT option_id FROM eav_attribute_option );
DELETE FROM eav_attribute_label WHERE attribute_id IN ( SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code LIKE "attribute%");
DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code LIKE "attribute%";
DELETE FROM eav_attribute_group WHERE attribute_set_id IN ( SELECT attribute_set_id FROM eav_attribute_set WHERE attribute_set_name LIKE "Product Set%" );
DELETE FROM eav_attribute_set WHERE attribute_set_name LIKE "Product Set%";
```

Then Reindex all

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

For now I have deleted Dummy data Categories manually from the admin area. You have to delete those all categories having name "Category*".