# Magento 2 Remove SampleData failed

Tags: magento2.2.4, sample-data

I have installed Magento 2.2.4 with sample data. Now I need to remove all sample data, and I found a solution from [Magento DevDoc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-sample-data-other.html)

I used command as suggested,

```
php bin/magento sampledata:remove
```

But I got this error as following,

```
Loading composer repositories with package information

Removal failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                   
  The 'https://repo.magento.com/packages.json' URL required authentication.  
  You must be using the interactive console to authenticate
```

What did I miss?

Comment: did you get the solution??? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @AsadKhan I gave up the command line to remove the teste data on that site that didn't work. So I removed all test data directly in database with mysql query.

Comment: then can you please share the query if you still have???

Comment: @AsadKhan Sorry, I actually confused myself. the mysql query I used was for removing the test data that is generated from Performance Tookit. not for SampleData. So I haven't really solved the problem with removing the sampleData by using command line.

In case you need to remove Performance Toolkit genereated data, you can refer to this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/242423/26668

Answer (score 0):

in your Magento root folder, you will found auth.json.sample just rename it to auth.json and add your public and privet key  from your marketplace account